# selenium Not Running Javascript

Tags: python, selenium, bots

I can't access Tidal site with selenium. It is detected. How can I overcome this problem. My code is below. I am attaching the error I got.

```
   proxies = proxy()
   print(proxies)
   options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
   options.add_argument('--proxy-server=http://%s' % proxies)
   options.binary_location = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
   driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\/path/to/chromedriver.exe', options=options)
   driver.get("https://tidal.com/")
```

ERROR

**You are blocked.
This verification is required because your browser's behavior has come to our attention.
We can explain it this way:
You may be searching and clicking faster than expected by a human
Something might be preventing your javascript from working
There may be another robot with the same IP address as you (IP 88.244.90.77)
Having trouble accessing the site? Ask for Help**

Comment: I could not do the "cdc" logic suggested on the page you posted. I don't know much. Is there a video showing how to do it?

Comment: SO is not Udemy...